# how can i change list with custom tag in jsp?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, append, custom-tag

I faced following problem with custom tag in JSP. 
html content list generated by div custom tag when page loading end.
after that, i want to replace the list with ajax`s new data.
first, I emptied old list. and i made a html string(pdListHtml), append it.
but I cant get any new list at all.
please point me out if there is something wrong with the code.
thanks.

html.jsp

```
<ul class="pdImgType">
    <c:forEach var="goods" items="${goods}">    
        <div class="pdList">
            <pt:product prdNm="${goods.goods_name}" dispPrc="${goods.goods_origin_price }"/>
        </div>    
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Ajax JS

```
const filterParam = $("#submitForm").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "/ctgrSearchFilter.do",
    data : filterParam,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {               
        $(".pdImgType").empty();
        const goods = data.result.goods;        

        for(let i=0 ; i < goods.length ; i++){
            let pdListHtml = "";
            pdListHtml += '<div class=\"pdList\">';
            pdListHtml += '<pt\:product prdNm=\"'+ goods[i].goods_name +'\" dispPrc=\"'+ goods[i].goods_origin_price +'\"/>';
            pdListHtml += '</div>';
             $(".pdImgType").append(pdListHtml);
        }                
     },
     error : function(err) {
         alert("error");
     }
});
```

data from java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ctgrSearchFilter.do" , method = equestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject ctgrSrhFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    ModelAndView mv = commSearchService.callSearchAllNewAPI(request); 
    logger.info(">>>> ctgr result mv : "+ mv);       
    json.put("result",  mv.getModel());

    return json;
}
```

console log in java

ctgr result mv : ModelAndView: materialized View is [null]; model is {cateCntTot=0, cate=[], brand1List=[], delryList=[], total=1254, goods=[{goods_name=nice, goods_origin_price=109000}]}

Comment: Can you add `data` output in your question as well?

Comment: hi .@Swati. i added data and console log in java. thank you about your concern.

Comment: I found that it just added html not custom tag run. how can i get custom tag result not just html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `goods` using `data.goods` and then loop over it .Also ,check if your `json` is valid or not .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your json response
var data = {
  "cateCntTot": 0,
  "cate": [],
  "brand1List": [],
  "delryList": [],
  "total": 1254,
  "goods": [{
    "goods_name": "nice",
    "goods_origin_price": 109000
  }]
};
var pdListHtml = "";
///fetching data->goods
var goods = data.goods;
for (let i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {

  //your html 
  /*pdListHtml += '<div class=\"pdList\" style="background:yellow"><pt\:product prdNm=\"' + goods[i].goods_name + '\" dispPrc=\"' + goods[i].goods_origin_price + '\"/></div>';*/
  
  //demo data to append
  pdListHtml += '<div class=\"pdList\" style="background:lightblue">prdNm :' + goods[i].goods_name + ' <br/>dispPrc :' + goods[i].goods_origin_price + '</div>'


}
//add data under pdImgType class 
$(".pdImgType").html(pdListHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="pdImgType">
  <c:forEach var="goods" items="${goods}">
    <div class="pdList">
      <pt:product prdNm="${goods.goods_name}" dispPrc="${goods.goods_origin_price }" />
    </div>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help.I found out if  i want to apply html string, i  needed to reload on my page. thanks!!